# Call default module export from other export?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

Say you have this ES6 module:

```
// ./foobar.js
export default function(txt)
{
    // Do something with txt
    return txt;
}
```

Is it possible to add another function export to the same file, that *uses* this default function? I assume it's possible, but how do you call it?

```
// ./foobar.js
export default function(txt)
{
    // Do something with txt
    return txt;
}

export function doSomethingMore(txt)
{
    txt = // ? how to call default function ?
    // Do something more with txt
    return txt;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can give it a name, and it’ll be in scope:

```
export default function foo(txt) {
    // Do something with txt
    return txt;
}

export function bar(txt) {
    txt = foo(txt);
    return txt;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can either create the function then export it or just name the function

```
export default function myDefault () {
  // code
}

export function doSomething () {
  myDefault()
}
```

or

```
function myDefault () {

}

export function doSomething () {
  myDefault()
}

export default myDefault
```

Answer (score 1):

Try exporting a reference to the function:

```
var theFunc = function(txt)
{
// Do something with txt
return txt;
}

export default theFunc
```

Then you can reference `theFunc` elsewhere.